# Peterson's quantum cohomology of G/P lectures

Tags: lie-groups, soft-question, flag-varieties, online-resources

Dale Peterson famously gave a series of lectures on the quantum cohomology of flag varieties $G/P$ at MIT in 1997. These lectures are often cited in subsequent papers by other authors on the subject (where many of the proofs appear for the first time in the literature), as Peterson himself never published any of this work to my understanding.

I have always assumed that these citations were to acknowledge Peterson with the result, and not specifically referring to a written resource. However, [this paper](https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/articles/10.5802/alco.242/) references a *specific lecture* from the series. This leads me to ask:

1. Does an actual resource from Peterson's lecture series exist, in typed/written/photocopied/etc. form?
2. If so, is that resource obtainable in an "ethical" way (meaning, not going against Peterson's intentions in terms of distribution)?

Comment: There is this typed version: http://math.soimeme.org/~arunram/Resources/QuantumCohomologyOfGPL16-18.html      See the last two lines of the last page.

Comment: @FZaldivar Thank you, this is precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put it as an answer to keep the page from jumping to the front from time to time:

There is this typed version, see the last two lines of the last page:

[http://math.soimeme.org/~arunram/Resources/QuantumCohomologyOfGPL16-18.html](http://math.soimeme.org/%7Earunram/Resources/QuantumCohomologyOfGPL16-18.html)

Following Sam Hopkins's comment, the link to the first lecture is:

[http://math.soimeme.org/~arunram/Resources/QuantumCohomologyOfGPL1-5.html](http://math.soimeme.org/%7Earunram/Resources/QuantumCohomologyOfGPL1-5.html)
and additionally, there are handwritten notes in a link provided by him.

Comment: It looks like the handwritten notes themselves are also available at: http://math.soimeme.org/~arunram/Resources/PetersonGmodBcourse1997.pdf

Comment: And it probably makes more sense to link to lecture 1 than lecture 16, right?: http://math.soimeme.org/~arunram/Resources/QuantumCohomologyOfGPL1-5.html

Comment: @Sam Hopkins, thanks!  I have added the corresponding link to the answer.